# Criar um evento para excluir a partir de um tempo

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um evento que exclui registros dentro da tabela que é executado a cada 5 minutos.Com os seguintes parâmetros

```
DELETE FROM redefinirsenha WHERE `Data` < NOW()
```

Porém queria fazer este evento ser executado a cada 1 minuto e deletasse os registros que estivesse na tabela mais que 5 minutos

Se alguém puder ajudar ficarei muito grato

Desculpe se a pergunta não ficou muito esclarecida sou novo aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o `INTERVAL` para calcular os 5 minutos na query:

```
DELETE FROM redefinirsenha WHERE `Data` < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

Comment: ok muito obrigado resolveu o meu problema